# NHibernate mapping with getdate() sql function in where-attribute

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, sqlite

I have a mapping that retrieves all active roles for a user. I use the where attribute to filter out roles in the hbm mapping. The mapping look like this:

```
<map name="Bar" table="Foo_Bar" lazy="true" cascade="all" inverse="false" where="intGroupId Is Null And dtmExpires > getdate()">
<cache usage="read-write"/>
<key column="intUserId"/>
<index column="varRole" type="string"/>
<one-to-many class="Foo.Bar, Foo"/>
</map>
```

This works great in production on a SQL Server, but in my unit tests where I use SQLite the getdate() function isn't recognized.

How can I modify my mapping so it works in both MS SQL Server and SQLite, but still have the filter?

// Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about SQLite but you may be able to use

```
intGroupId Is Null And dtmExpires > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the SQL Standard equivalent of getdate(), and I believe it is implemented in SQLite (and I'm positive it is in SQL Server).

You may be able to use the technique discussed [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2009/08/17/adjusting-nhibernate-mapping-for-tests.aspx) to tweak your mappings at runtime if this doesn't work.